# a command line output error generates while installing java on the system

Tags: command-line

```
Archive:  /home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe
[/home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  /home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe may be a plain executable, not an archive
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe or
          /home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/gaurav/Desktop/java/JavaSetup6u27.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't install a Windows Java program natively in a Linux OS. Packages in the Ubuntu Software Center have the .deb format, not the .exe format used by Windows executable files. In the Ubuntu Software Center search for OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime (*openjdk-7-jre*) and install it. There is also a developer version of Java in the Ubuntu Software Center, but you probably don't need it.

Installing OpenJDK is not enough for enabling Java in web browsers. You'll also need to install the *icedtea-7-plugin* package. However under normal conditions, it is not at all necessary to enable Java in web browsers, and if you don't install it you'll probably find that you don't need it either.